# Java reading every other line in text file

Tags: java, bluej

I've written some code that has a scanner read from a text file on my computer, but when running the code, the scanner only reads every other number that's in the text file.. any ideas?

Note: For the grades.txt, this is the file

"3 8 1 13 18 15 7 17 1 14"

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class GradeAverage
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Media - Graphics\\Documents\\SCHOOL\\NCVPS\\GradeAverage\\grades.txt"));
                int i = 0;
                int sum = 0;
                int lineNumber = 0;
                int average = 0;
                while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
                System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
                sum = sum+scanner.nextInt();
                lineNumber++;
                    }
                    System.out.println("The sum of the numbers: "+sum);
                    System.out.println("The number of scores: "+lineNumber);
                    average = sum/lineNumber;
                    System.out.println("The average of the numbers: "+average);
        }        
    }
```

Here's what it outputs:

3

1

18

7

1

The sum of the numbers: 67

The number of scores: 5

The average of the numbers: 13

Comment: You're calling scanner.nextInt twice inside the loop. Save scanner.nextInt() to an int variable, then print the variable and add the variable to the sum. You'll notice 67=8+13+15+17+14

Comment: You have two calls to `scanner.nextInt()` in your loop.  Each one reads a number.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `nextInt()` in your loop, you consume one `int`. So when you do

```
System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
sum = sum+scanner.nextInt();
```

You consume two `int`(s). You want something like

```
int t = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println(t);
sum += t;
```

Also your `average` is currently an `int` (I would expect a `float` or `double`).

```
double average = sum/(double)lineNumber;
```

Don't forget to remove `int average = 0;` (or modify this and `average` accordingly).